# Simple for loop to calculate headers size based on a specific ratio

Tags: javascript, beginner

How can I improve the following for loop (wannabe function) to create harmonic sizes for headers based on a specific ratio?

```
var base = 16;
var goldenRatio = 1.618;
var list = "";
for(var i=6; i>0; i--){
    list = "\nh" + i + " { font-size: " + base + "px; }" + list;
    base *= Math.round(base*goldenRatio);
}   
console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code produces and I'm wondering if this really what you want:

```
"
h1 { font-size: 1.0957612059345655e+45px; }
h2 { font-size: 2.602367950332107e+22px; }
h3 { font-size: 126822144384px; }
h4 { font-size: 279968px; }
h5 { font-size: 416px; }
h6 { font-size: 16px; }"
```

The numbers are huge. Looking at [this page](http://type-scale.com/), it seems you should not have `base` inside the multiplication here:

> ```
> base *= Math.round(base*goldenRatio);
> ```

Also, by rounding at this step, you lose precision. It would be better to round right before you put the value in the string. Like this:

```
var base = 16;
var list = "";
for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
    list = "\nh" + i + " { font-size: " + Math.round(base) + "px; }" + list;
    base *= goldenRatio;
}
```

I'm also wondering if you really want the `\n` at the start of the resulting string.
It would seem more natural to put it at the end of each line, like this:

```
list = "h" + i + " { font-size: " + Math.round(base) + "px; }\n" + list;
```

Notice also that I added more spaces around the operators in the `for`.
There is no real standard for this in JavaScript,
but this is a practice I borrow from other languages where it is a standard,
for improved readability. Compare these two versions, I hope you'll agree that this is an improvement:

> ```
> for(var i=6; i>0; i--){
>
> for (var i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
> ```

Comment: Hi Janos, thank you for correcting the code, and, yes, that's what I want, copying it from console, instead of using `base = base*1.618` I refactored it a little bit to better present it on Code Review getting the opposite result. :)
In any case, is there a better, more elegant way, to get that same result or the for loop is (was) acceptable? I felt it could have been improved someway.
Thank you again for your time.

Comment: I added one more point about formatting. Other than what I mentioned, I don't really see further possible improvement in this short piece of code.